# Reducing math font in tikz pgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

my tick numbers are overlapping, reducing the fontsize with `\tiny` just change the size of the `x` but the subindex keeps the same size. How can I reduce the size also of the subindexes in the tick labels?

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass\[10pt,a4paper\]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
        domain=2:8,
        samples=7
    },
    integral fill/.style={
        integral,
        draw=none, fill=#1,
    },
    integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
    integral line/.style={
        integral,
        very thick,
        draw=#1
    },
    integral line/.default=black,
  every tick label/.append style={font=\large}
}



\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}\[
                % The function that is used for all the plots
                declare function={f(\x)=\x/5-cos(deg(\x*1.85))/2+2;}
                \]
                \begin{axis}\[
                integral axis,
                ymin=0,
                xmin=0.75, xmax=9.25,
                domain=1.5:8.5,
                xtick={2,2.5,3,3.5,...,8},
                xticklabels={$x_0$, $x_{1/2}$, $x_1$,$x_{3/2}$,$x_2$,$x_{5/2}$,$x_3$,,,,$x_{N-1}$,$x_{N-\frac{1}{2}}$,$x_N$},
                axis on top
                \]
                \addplot \[integral fill=cyan!15\] {f(x)} \closedcycle;
                \addplot \[very thick, cyan!75!blue\] {f(x)} node \[anchor=south\] {$y=f(x)$};
                \addplot \[integral line=black\] {f(x)};
                \addplot \[integral, ycomb\] {f(x)};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about rotating the tick labels instead of making them smaller?

Comment: Hi mr. Marmot, nice Idea, how to do it?

Comment: You could just add `xticklabel style={rotate=-45,anchor=north west}` to the options of the `axis`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
        domain=2:8,
        samples=7
    },
    integral fill/.style={
        integral,
        draw=none, fill=#1,
    },
    integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
    integral line/.style={
        integral,
        very thick,
        draw=#1
    },
    integral line/.default=black,
  every tick label/.append style={font=\large}
}



\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                % The function that is used for all the plots
                declare function={f(\x)=\x/5-cos(deg(\x*1.85))/2+2;}
                ]
                \begin{axis}[
                integral axis,
                ymin=0,
                xmin=0.75, xmax=9.25,
                domain=1.5:8.5,
                xtick={2,2.5,3,3.5,...,8},
                xticklabels={$x_0$, $x_{1/2}$, $x_1$,$x_{3/2}$,$x_2$,$x_{5/2}$,$x_3$,,,,$x_{N-1}$,$x_{N-\frac{1}{2}}$,$x_N$},
                axis on top,
                xticklabel style={rotate=-45,anchor=north west,yshift=5pt}
                ]
                \addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f(x)} \closedcycle;
                \addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f(x)} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};
                \addplot [integral line=black] {f(x)};
                \addplot [integral, ycomb] {f(x)};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scalerel` package and `scaleto`,

```
$x_{\scaleto{0}{3pt}}$
```

Will produce

[image]

Where `$x_{0}$` produces

[image]